# Why my omp.h path isn't being recognized?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, openmp

My problems console in Visual Studio Code is showing me the following up message:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. InteliSense features for this translation unit
cannot open source file "omp.h"
```

This message is being showed even after I linked the path of omp.h after found it with:

```
find /usr -name omp.h
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/omp.h",
            "/usr/include/c++/7.2.0",
            "/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/lib/clang/5.0.0/include",
            "/usr/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/omp.h",
                "/usr/include/c++/7.2.0",
                "/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/clang/5.0.0/include",
                "/usr/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing out? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed changing the path to:

```
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/"
```

Removing the omp.h file.